# Why async not help to wait result?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

android studio 3.6

I need to call method `getFuelPrice` and ONLY AFTER IT FINISH then call another code.

snippet:

```
      for (currentPass in 0..10) {
        viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                currentRecognizedCheck = getFuelPrice(currentRecognizedCheck)
                            }
}


suspend fun getFuelPrice(currentRecognizedCheck: Check): Check {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = TransportService.getFuelPricesList(
                currentRecognizedCheck.date!!
            )
        }
        return currentRecognizedCheck
    }


suspend fun getFuelPricesList(
            date: Date,
            isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false
        ): Response<*> {
            Debug.d(TAG, "getFuelPricesList: tangoContoRestClient = $tangoContoRestClient")
            suspend fun execOperation(): Response<*> =
                tangoContoRestClient.getFuelPricesList(date)
            return runOperation(isCustomtHandle, ::execOperation)
        }
```

But the method `getFuelPricesList` call every time. Why? Why `viewModelScope.async`  not help ?

Comment: getFuelPriceList is called in getFuelPrice so ofc its called whenever getFuelPrice is called.
You could investigate into invokeOnCompletion

Comment: If your first (broken) snippet is not within a suspendable context, then all you can do is block the thread until the coroutine is done. In that case all your coroutine work is for nothing. And, if it is inside a suspendable context (as it should be), then just call the function without `async`.

Comment: Can you describe your use-case of what you wanted to achieve and why? Because currently as @Traendy mentioned, your code will always execute inside AND the variable `response` is set, but you never use it so I'm asking myself what you actually want there?!